# Uncertain how to send a long value as hidden to action from in struts from a jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, struts

I wish to send a long value from my `login.jsp` page to the struts action from bean as a hidden field. I have done the mapping etc for the two properties username and password and for them the program works fine. Now I want to send a time value as a hidden property named "requesttime" to store the time of login in a table for security check. But I have not been able to figure out how to do it. Here is the part of the jsp page where I am stuck.

```
<%long time = System.currentTimeMillis();%>
<html:form action="login">
    <bean:message key="login.username"/>
    <html:text property="username"/><br/>
    <bean:message key="login.password"/>
    <html:password property="password"/><br/>
    <%--I wish to insert "time" as property "requesttime" as hidden here--%>
    <html:submit value="login"/>     
</html:form><hr/>
<html:errors/>
```

Please do not mind my ignorance. And thank you for whatever help you may provide.

Comment: What's the issue? And why should that be sent by the client anyway? Does your server not know what time it is?

Comment: The idea is to send time as a part of the login request so that if someone tries to resend the request by refreshing the page the server would know that it is an old request being resend.

Answer (score 0):

Using script you can get the time of login. Now do
    < input type="hidden" id="time">
and enter the value you got. Using scriplets would be better.
Then in servlet call the request.getParameter("time") and store as a string or as an integer.
 Your choice. Hope this helps.....